# the size of vfprintf in libc symbol table is so big, why?

Tags: symbols, glibc, elf

$ readelf -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so

below is a line from the cmd ouput

Num:      Value      Size    Type     Bind    Vis      Ndx Name

2261: 00040130 **20136** FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 vfprintf@@GLIBC_2.0

Could some nice buddy tell me why the size of vfprintf is so big?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because `vfprintf` is where the real work is done. `printf`, `fprintf` and `vprintf` just wrap around it.

`sprintf`, `snprintf`, `vsprintf` and `vsnprintf` create a string stream and pass it to `vfprintf`.